# Amazon S3 with Route 53 for static hosting - shared namespace

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-route53, bucket

I'm currently attempting to use Amazon S3 for static hosting for a domain with the word `bucket` in the URL. One of the requirements for static hosting is that the bucket is named after the domain, so I had success setting up `bucketdomain.com` (not the actual domain) but unfortunatley I am unable to setup `www.bucketdomain.com` as S3 returns the following error when creating the S3 bucket:

> The requested bucket name is not available. The bucket namespace is
>   shared by all users of the system. Please select a different name and
>   try again.

Does anyone know a way round this issue?

Answer (score 0):

S3 buckets are a global namespace, and so it's very possible that someone else took the same bucket before you could get it. It's also possible that due to internal replication delays or other such issues, a previously-deleted bucket is not yet available for re-use.

It appears the bucket name you are using is not *unique* enough.

Comment: The problem is they require the namespace to be identical to the domain name. Any way round this?